# python cv2.matchTemplate получить наиболее подходящий результат

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-3.5, numpy

Всем доброго времени суток.
Есть большая картинка *90173.png*
На ней несколько (заведомо неизвестно сколько) изображений *2.png*
Задача вывести координаты максимально подходящих точек совпадений.

Код:

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np

source = cv2.imread('90173.png')
object1 = cv2.imread('2.png')
result = cv2.matchTemplate(source,object1,cv2.TM_SQDIFF)

result2 = np.reshape(result, result.shape[0]*result.shape[1])
sort = np.argsort(result2)

#10 статичная цифра взятая с потолка

for i in range(10):
    (y1, x1) = np.unravel_index(sort[i], result.shape)
print (x1,y1)
```

Сейчас при таком коде выводится 10 вариантов координат. Нужных только 2. Остальные 8 координаты поблизости (как максимально похожие).
Как сделать так, чтобы выводились только первые 2?

Примеры картинок:
[image: 90173]
2:
[image: 2]

Comment: Вы можете выложить ссылки на примеры картинок, чтобы можно было воспроизвести ваши результаты?

Comment: @MaxU, Приложил. Собственно "2" - это вырезанное изображение с этой же картинки. Сейчас он находит самостоятельную цифру 2, и цифру 2 в цифре 12 (нижний ряд игнорирует, там цифра меньше и так и должно быть). Нужно обработать огромное количество картинок, где цифр "2" может быть и больше

Comment: хммм... что-то у меня эта двойка не находится: `result: array([[ 0.]], dtype=float32)`

Comment: похоже `i.stack.imgur.com` "подправил" картинки... Вы можете их выложить на какой-нибудь свободный (без регистрации и логина) файлообменник?

Comment: @MaxU, http://rezonov.ru/90173.png, http://rezonov.ru/2.png
Попробуйте так. Выложил на свой хостинг

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать вот так:

Следующую часть я скопировал из вашего вопроса без изменений:

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np

source = cv2.imread('90173.png')
object1 = cv2.imread('2.png')
result = cv2.matchTemplate(source,object1,cv2.TM_SQDIFF)
```

Нахождение координат первых двух точек:

```
y,x = np.unravel_index(np.argsort(result.reshape(-1,)), result.shape)

coords = np.column_stack((x[:2], y[:2]))
```

Результат:

```
In [87]: coords
Out[87]:
array([[   2,  267],
       [1265,  562]], dtype=int64)
```

первая точка:

```
In [88]: coords[0]
Out[88]: array([  2, 267], dtype=int64)
```

вторая точка:

```
In [89]: coords[1]
Out[89]: array([1265,  562], dtype=int64)
```